# ffmpeg itsoffset doesn't work with pcm audio and raw 264 video

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I need to create an MP4 container with data from a hardware encoder. The encoder outputs PCM 16-bit signed audio and raw H.264 ES video frames.

This `ffmpeg` command line I've got works but the audio and video are not sync'd.

From other posts I know that [`itsoffset` only works with video](https://superuser.com/questions/982342/in-ffmpeg-how-to-delay-only-the-audio-of-a-mp4-video-without-converting-the-au) and probably [doesn't work with `-v copy`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116430/ffmpeg-stream-offset-command-itsoffset-not-working)

I've confirmed that applying an `itsoffset` has no effect.

Here's the command line.  Any suggestions?

One post suggested `itsoffset` works if you re-encode the video.  But doing that needs CPU power and adds latency. (And what's the point of a hardware encoder then?)

```
ffmpeg -f s16le -ar 44.1k -ac 2      -i Audio_20190110-165736.pcm 
       -fflags +genpts -itsoffset -5 -i Video_20190110-165736.264
       -c:v copy -c:a aac -b:a 128k 
       -f mp4 -movflags +faststart  output.mp4
```

**EDIT I**

Here is a link to [the audio/video input files](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/9ntzlzywdzhq5f3/AAApE41sWmqkwEiipL-ezzXCa?dl=0) referenced in the above command.

Comment: I can check in a couple of days as I'm out of town but itsoffset isn't limited to video. Check the output with VLC.

Comment: Thanks, let me know. Multiple postings said it doesn't work for audio. Also, my own testing shows no effect whether applied to the audio or video input.  I can post the source files if need be.  (for testing, using the command line above, modify `itsoffset` and playback on VLC. Always the same)

Comment: Works for me. You should apply the offset before the audio input only and have it be a positive number. If the audio is "early" , skip the offset and apply a `-ss X` to trim out the first X seconds of the audio. Make sure you're using a recent ffmpeg build (>3.4)

Comment: Indeed, the audio is early. I'll try the `-ss X` next chance I get. Thanks!

Comment: Yes!  That did it.  Thanks.  If you copy/paste that into an answer, I'll accept as correct :-)   I also had to play with the audio sample rate to "stretch" the audio to match the video duration. The audio would match at the beginning of the clip but be off by the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-itsoffset` works on all types of files - the application is media-agnostic.

However, ffmpeg has two concerns in terms of writing output file timestamps: syncing the various streams and avoiding negative timestamps depending on the output format constraints. In order to do so, ffmpeg may manipulate timestamps of one or more streams after the offset has been applied. This can produce unintended effects.

For reliable use of itsoffset, it should be a positive number where possible, be preferably applied to audio-only inputs where possible. If one wishes to bring **audio** forward, skipping the earlier content, use `-ss X` before the audio input. To do the same to video, you can do the same but transcoding is usually required for intended result.